# ctypes float rubbish return

Tags: python, ctypes

I've faced with a problem when I tried to load float into python program using `ctypes`

C code:

```
float test_ret_float(){
  return 1.0;
}
```

In Python, all ways rubbish resulted:

```
print lib.test_ret_float()
>>1074161254
print c_float(lib.test_ret_float()).value
>>1074161280.0
```

In case of `int` all works fine.

It seems, that type conversation doesn't work as expected and really returns `raw` 4byte value that converts not to `float` but `int`, why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was that I missed `restype` to setup:

```
lib.test_ret_float.restype = c_float
```

That solves the problem

Comment: The reason is that a `float` is returned from either the FPU stack (e.g. x87 `fstp` instruction), or in x64 it uses an SSE register (e.g. `xmm0`). So a `c_float` or `c_double` return type has to be handled specially. The default `c_int` result (e.g. from register `rax` in x64) is garbage that has nothing to do with the function's return value.

Answer (score 2):

I know it is **way too late** but to whoever searches this and might be looking to the same issue I had.

Usage: if you passed a pointer to a variable as and argument and the C function changes replaces it with a floating point, this way you can repackage the python interpretation (integer) value to a signaled 32bit floating point

```
def ieee754(value):
    """Repackages values to 32bit floating point"""
    packed_v = struct.pack('>L', value)
    return struct.unpack('>f', packed_v)[0]
```